# Powershell: Launch program on everyones PC as fast as possible

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, execution, launch

I have a program that I need to execute to a list of about 200 PCs in parallel as fast as possible. However when launching this script it takes at least 30 seconds before the program appears.

This is for a duress alarm (e.g. armed gunman etc.) so needs to launch to everyone's machine as quickly as possible.

Below is the script I am currently using but it still takes at least 30 seconds to launch. Can someone please advise on how I could speed this up?

Thanks

```
Get-Content "C:\remotecommand\psexec\computers.txt"  | %{

# Define what each job does

  $ScriptBlock = {
    C:\remotecommand\psexec\PsExec.exe -s -i -d \\$args "C:\Windows\DURESS ALARM.exe"
    #Start-Sleep 15
  }

  # Execute the jobs in parallel

  Write-Host $ScriptBlock
  Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $_
}

Get-Job

# Wait for it all to complete

While (Get-Job -State "Running")
{
  Start-Sleep 10
}

# Getting the information back from the jobs

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: When I start  Powershell on my own local machine, it takes about 10-15 seconds. You're expecting PSExec (which adds overhead) and network remote access (which also adds overhead) to perform better than is possible. Powershell and PSExec are the wrong tools for this task. *I need to go from 0-60 miles per hour in 10 seconds. I've chosen a dump truck as my vehicle, and loaded it with 3 tons of stone. Why isn't it going fast enough?*

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite, this is not the right tool for the job.  In fact, I don't think this should be anything but a backup to a more reliable system (i.e. one that doesn't depend on networks, systems not being in the middle of a reboot, etc).  Having said that, if you want something like this that is faster, you probably need a system service that runs on each PC listening for incoming requests from a dedicated client app. Not to make light of a possible tragic situation, but I'm glad I live somewhere that an 'armed gunman' is the last thing I need to code for.

Comment: I would start a process on each machine at boot time that waits for a semaphore then displays the alert. Then when the alarm occurs, just give the semaphore and all waiting machines will display the alert.